# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'geometry'

Tags: python, pandas, geometry, geopandas, dask-dataframe

I'm trying to get longitude and latitude of areas in Indonesia using `dask_geopandas` and `Nominatim` library in python pandas dataframe. But, it always returns error. The latest error that I get:

`__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'geometry'`

This is the code I'm using recently:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import dask_geopandas as dask_gpd
import pandas as pd
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
import numpy as np

ddf = dd.from_pandas(df_cleaned, npartitions=4)

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="my_geocoder")

def geocode_area(area):
    try:
        location = geolocator.geocode(area)
        return (location.latitude, location.longitude)
    except:
        return (np.nan, np.nan)

ddf['latitude'] = np.nan
ddf['longitude'] = np.nan

ddf['latitude'], ddf['longitude'] = ddf['kodya / kab'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(geocode_area(x)))

dask_gdf = dask_gpd.GeoDataFrame(ddf, geometry=dask_gpd.points_from_xy(ddf.longitude, ddf.latitude), crs='EPSG:4326')

ddf = dask_gdf.drop(columns=['geometry']).compute()

ddf.to_csv('processed_data.csv', index=False)
```

What is the possible right code for this case? I just want to get a pandas dataframe with longitude and latitude based on `kodya / kab`. The dataframe consists of 17000++ rows. Thank u in advance.

Comment: You can’t initialize a dask GeoDataFrame this way. See the api doc: https://dask-geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/docs/reference/api/dask_geopandas.GeoDataFrame.html#dask_geopandas.GeoDataFrame

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [from_dask_dataframe](https://dask-geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/reference/api/dask_geopandas.from_dask_dataframe.html) instead:

```py
dask_gdf = dask_gpd.from_dask_dataframe(ddf, geometry=dask_gpd.points_from_xy(ddf.longitude, ddf.latitude))
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer! but it returns this error `KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,\n            ...\n            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],\n           dtype='int64', length=4028)] are in the [index]"`

Comment: That’s a different error. This is the correct answer to your question. If you’re having a different issue, try to debug it first by looking it up and trying to understand the issue, then feel free to post a new question if you’re still stuck. Make sure you do look for other answers before asking - both of these error messages are well covered by other questions. Good luck!